# Black background when downloading png image in android

Tags: android, image

i stuck in very serious problem.when i am downloading png image from server than, i can get black background in the image. how can i remove this black background from an image at the time of downloading?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Image change extension .png while you download image then change background color pixel by pixel cut on image and return new bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Do you save your image on the device using PNG format too ?